# TPM Normalization for Seurat Class DataSet

Tags: r, normalization, seurat

I would like to normalize the data in a seurat object using TPM Normalization. For this I need to extract the count matrix from the seurat object. Thus need help on this aspect.

I used the following code to execute the same:

```
Brain_Tumor_3p_filtered_feature_bc_matrix_seurat <- NormalizeTPM(Brain_Tumor_3p_filtered_feature_bc_matrix_seurat, sce = NULL, tr_length = NULL, log = FALSE,scale = 1, pseudo.count = log(0))
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Converting input to matrix.

Error in as.vector(data) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

I tried to convert my Seurat object to SingleCellExperiment beforehand and run:

```
Brain_Tumor_3p_filtered_feature_bc_matrix_seurat_SingleCellExperiment<-as.SingleCellExperiment(Brain_Tumor_3p_filtered_feature_bc_matrix_seurat)

NormalizeTPM(sce=Brain_Tumor_3p_filtered_feature_bc_matrix_seurat_SingleCellExperiment, tr_length = NULL, log = FALSE,scale = 1, pseudo.count = log(0))
```

This still produces an error:

```
Error in `assays<-`(`*tmp*`, withDimnames = withDimnames, ..., value = `*vtmp*`) : 
  please use 'assay(x, withDimnames=FALSE)) <- value' or 'assays(x, withDimnames=FALSE)) <- value'
  when the rownames or colnames of the supplied assay(s) are not identical to those of the
  receiving SingleCellExperiment object 'x'
```

Find a sample of the data here:

```
dput(Brain_Tumor_3p_filtered_feature_bc_matrix_seurat[1:20,1:20])

new("Seurat", assays = list(RNA = new("Assay", counts = new("dgCMatrix", 
    i = c(3L, 8L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 5L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 
    14L, 8L, 9L, 18L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 8L, 8L, 13L, 15L, 1L, 4L, 
    8L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 8L, 13L, 2L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 8L, 14L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 
    8L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 3L, 8L, 1L), p = c(0L, 
    5L, 9L, 13L, 16L, 19L, 20L, 23L, 30L, 30L, 33L, 39L, 41L, 
    45L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 55L, 59L, 61L, 62L), Dim = c(20L, 20L
    ), Dimnames = list(c("AL627309.5", "LINC01409", "FAM87B", 
    "LINC01128", "LINC00115", "FAM41C", "AL645608.2", "SAMD11", 
    "NOC2L", "KLHL17", "PLEKHN1", "PERM1", "AL645608.7", "HES4", 
    "ISG15", "AGRN", "C1orf159", "TTLL10", "TNFRSF18", "TNFRSF4"
    ), c("AAACGAAAGAGAACCC-1", "AAACGCTGTACGCTAT-1", "AAAGGGCAGTAACCGG-1", 
    "AAATGGAAGTACCCTA-1", "AACAACCTCCCTCGAT-1", "AACAAGAGTCAGATTC-1", 
    "AACAGGGAGGTGCATG-1", "AACCAACAGAAATGGG-1", "AACCACAAGTTACGTC-1", 
    "AACCACACAAATGCGG-1", "AACCACACACCAGTAT-1", "AACCACATCCCGTTGT-1", 
    "AACCATGCATGACAGG-1", "AACCTGAAGGTAGATT-1", "AACCTTTTCCGCAACG-1", 
    "AAGAACAGTCGTTGGC-1", "AAGCGAGGTCGCGTTG-1", "AAGCGAGTCTAAGCCA-1", 
    "AAGCGTTAGAGAGCAA-1", "AAGCGTTAGCCTGTGC-1")), x = c(1, 1, 
    1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
    2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 10, 1, 2, 1, 5, 3, 1, 5, 2, 6, 2, 1, 
    1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 20, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 
    1, 3, 1), factors = list()), data = new("dgCMatrix", i = c(3L, 
8L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 5L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 8L, 9L, 
18L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 8L, 8L, 13L, 15L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
15L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 8L, 13L, 2L, 8L, 
13L, 14L, 1L, 8L, 14L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 3L, 8L, 
13L, 14L, 3L, 8L, 1L), p = c(0L, 5L, 9L, 13L, 16L, 19L, 20L, 
23L, 30L, 30L, 33L, 39L, 41L, 45L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 55L, 59L, 61L, 
62L), Dim = c(20L, 20L), Dimnames = list(c("AL627309.5", "LINC01409", 
"FAM87B", "LINC01128", "LINC00115", "FAM41C", "AL645608.2", "SAMD11", 
"NOC2L", "KLHL17", "PLEKHN1", "PERM1", "AL645608.7", "HES4", 
"ISG15", "AGRN", "C1orf159", "TTLL10", "TNFRSF18", "TNFRSF4"), 
    c("AAACGAAAGAGAACCC-1", "AAACGCTGTACGCTAT-1", "AAAGGGCAGTAACCGG-1", 
    "AAATGGAAGTACCCTA-1", "AACAACCTCCCTCGAT-1", "AACAAGAGTCAGATTC-1", 
    "AACAGGGAGGTGCATG-1", "AACCAACAGAAATGGG-1", "AACCACAAGTTACGTC-1", 
    "AACCACACAAATGCGG-1", "AACCACACACCAGTAT-1", "AACCACATCCCGTTGT-1", 
    "AACCATGCATGACAGG-1", "AACCTGAAGGTAGATT-1", "AACCTTTTCCGCAACG-1", 
    "AAGAACAGTCGTTGGC-1", "AAGCGAGGTCGCGTTG-1", "AAGCGAGTCTAAGCCA-1", 
    "AAGCGTTAGAGAGCAA-1", "AAGCGTTAGCCTGTGC-1")), x = c(1, 1, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 10, 1, 2, 1, 5, 3, 1, 5, 2, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 20, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1), factors = list()), 
    scale.data = structure(numeric(0), .Dim = c(0L, 0L)), key = "rna_", 
    assay.orig = NULL, var.features = character(0), meta.features = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c("AL627309.5", 
    "LINC01409", "FAM87B", "LINC01128", "LINC00115", "FAM41C", 
    "AL645608.2", "SAMD11", "NOC2L", "KLHL17", "PLEKHN1", "PERM1", 
    "AL645608.7", "HES4", "ISG15", "AGRN", "C1orf159", "TTLL10", 
    "TNFRSF18", "TNFRSF4"), class = "data.frame"), misc = list())), 
    meta.data = structure(list(orig.ident = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Brain_Tumor_3p_raw_feature_bc_matrix", class = "factor"), 
        nCount_RNA = c(8, 7, 9, 4, 4, 2, 5, 17, 0, 8, 19, 2, 
        5, 3, 1, 1, 26, 7, 4, 1), nFeature_RNA = c(5L, 4L, 4L, 
        3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
        4L, 2L, 1L), percent.Brain_Tumor_3p_filtered_feature_bc_matrix_seurat = c(5.73453284414736, 
        6.01779506968141, 3.55912743972445, 4.50131444820001, 
        1.02573056022348, 4.88421052631579, 3.52807510614124, 
        1.07083296761169, 9.39285409738211, 6.73866576667792, 
        4.57610789980732, 0.617430539064355, 6.66001496632577, 
        2.96102465225176, 4.46445802508845, 4.89557004123986, 
        7.83134851813312, 2.82530215036886, 5.54443053817272, 
        2.95155221072437)), row.names = c("AAACGAAAGAGAACCC-1", 
    "AAACGCTGTACGCTAT-1", "AAAGGGCAGTAACCGG-1", "AAATGGAAGTACCCTA-1", 
    "AACAACCTCCCTCGAT-1", "AACAAGAGTCAGATTC-1", "AACAGGGAGGTGCATG-1", 
    "AACCAACAGAAATGGG-1", "AACCACAAGTTACGTC-1", "AACCACACAAATGCGG-1", 
    "AACCACACACCAGTAT-1", "AACCACATCCCGTTGT-1", "AACCATGCATGACAGG-1", 
    "AACCTGAAGGTAGATT-1", "AACCTTTTCCGCAACG-1", "AAGAACAGTCGTTGGC-1", 
    "AAGCGAGGTCGCGTTG-1", "AAGCGAGTCTAAGCCA-1", "AAGCGTTAGAGAGCAA-1", 
    "AAGCGTTAGCCTGTGC-1"), class = "data.frame"), active.assay = "RNA", 
    active.ident = structure(c(`AAACGAAAGAGAACCC-1` = 1L, `AAACGCTGTACGCTAT-1` = 1L, 
    `AAAGGGCAGTAACCGG-1` = 1L, `AAATGGAAGTACCCTA-1` = 1L, `AACAACCTCCCTCGAT-1` = 1L, 
    `AACAAGAGTCAGATTC-1` = 1L, `AACAGGGAGGTGCATG-1` = 1L, `AACCAACAGAAATGGG-1` = 1L, 
    `AACCACAAGTTACGTC-1` = 1L, `AACCACACAAATGCGG-1` = 1L, `AACCACACACCAGTAT-1` = 1L, 
    `AACCACATCCCGTTGT-1` = 1L, `AACCATGCATGACAGG-1` = 1L, `AACCTGAAGGTAGATT-1` = 1L, 
    `AACCTTTTCCGCAACG-1` = 1L, `AAGAACAGTCGTTGGC-1` = 1L, `AAGCGAGGTCGCGTTG-1` = 1L, 
    `AAGCGAGTCTAAGCCA-1` = 1L, `AAGCGTTAGAGAGCAA-1` = 1L, `AAGCGTTAGCCTGTGC-1` = 1L
    ), .Label = "Brain_Tumor_3p_raw_feature_bc_matrix", class = "factor"), 
    graphs = list(), neighbors = list(), reductions = list(), 
    images = list(), project.name = "Brain_Tumor_3p_raw_feature_bc_matrix", 
    misc = list(), version = structure(list(c(4L, 1L, 0L)), class = c("package_version", 
    "numeric_version")), commands = list(), tools = list())
```

EDIT: I've added the sample of my seurat object for further idea into the dataset.

Comment: I guess your data is a sce object and not a matrix, so `NormalizeTPM(sce=Brain_Tumor_3p_filtered_feature_bc_matrix_seurat, tr_length = NULL, log = FALSE,scale = 1, pseudo.count = log(0))` may be more accurate

Comment: @Basti thank you, but it still gices an error
```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘assays’ for signature ‘"Seurat"’
```

Comment: Then you need to convert your Seurat object to SingleCellExperiment beforehand : `as.SingleCellExperiment(Brain_Tumor_3p_filtered_feature_bc_matrix_seurat)`

Comment: @Basti This again brings new error here:
Error in `assays<-`(`*tmp*`, withDimnames = withDimnames, ..., value = `*vtmp*`) : 
  please use 'assay(x, withDimnames=FALSE)) <- value' or 'assays(x, withDimnames=FALSE)) <- value'
  when the rownames or colnames of the supplied assay(s) are not identical to those of the
  receiving SingleCellExperiment object 'x'

Comment: It will be hard to help you on that point without your data because it is related to your own SingleCellExperiment object. You can have a look at this to see the test dataset which is working with NormalizeTPM : https://github.com/beyergroup/ADImpute/blob/1a81c44dc1f335bffddb82c0b0bd96e67429eb12/tests/testthat/test-Normalize.R

Comment: @Basti added a sample of data through dput() hope if this helps. i'll also try exploring the github link you pasted

Comment: I do not use the package ADImpute so I cannot tell you the advantage of this package but it seems to perform a selection of genes and if you have genes that are not part of the package list they are removed from the data, which is problematic because the size of the produced data is not is the same as the original SingleCellExperiment and will produce your error (see # Median length of all transcripts for a given gene here : https://rdrr.io/github/anacarolinaleote/ADImpute/src/R/Normalize.R). I suggest you to contact the package creator to understand this part.

Comment: @Basti many thanks, i've contacted the package creater. i shall wait for them to respond post which, i'll answer the question myself for everyone's benefit

Comment: Based on your example data, `NormalizeTPM(Brain_Tumor_3p_filtered_feature_bc_matrix_seurat@assays$RNA@counts, tr_length = NULL, log = FALSE,scale = 1, pseudo.count = log(0))` would work for the input matrix. You may have to manually add that data back into the Seurat object, in case some genes are indeed removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears @Basti is spot on with his observation of dropped rows.

You can always pad your TPM matrix with NaN and add it to the `Seurat` object as an assay, if that is what you want. Alternatively, you could filter the `Seurat` object to keep only the rows present in the TPM matrix and re-run.

Below is an example padding the missing data in the TPM matrix with NaN, as well as the alternative subsetting method:

```r
library(Seurat)
#> Attaching SeuratObject
#> Attaching sp
library(ADImpute)

Brain_Tumor_3p_filtered_feature_bc_matrix_seurat <- new("Seurat", assays = list(RNA = new("Assay", counts = new("dgCMatrix", 
    i = c(3L, 8L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 5L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 
    14L, 8L, 9L, 18L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 8L, 8L, 13L, 15L, 1L, 4L, 
    8L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 8L, 13L, 2L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 8L, 14L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 
    8L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 3L, 8L, 1L), p = c(0L, 
    5L, 9L, 13L, 16L, 19L, 20L, 23L, 30L, 30L, 33L, 39L, 41L, 
    45L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 55L, 59L, 61L, 62L), Dim = c(20L, 20L
    ), Dimnames = list(c("AL627309.5", "LINC01409", "FAM87B", 
    "LINC01128", "LINC00115", "FAM41C", "AL645608.2", "SAMD11", 
    "NOC2L", "KLHL17", "PLEKHN1", "PERM1", "AL645608.7", "HES4", 
    "ISG15", "AGRN", "C1orf159", "TTLL10", "TNFRSF18", "TNFRSF4"
    ), c("AAACGAAAGAGAACCC-1", "AAACGCTGTACGCTAT-1", "AAAGGGCAGTAACCGG-1", 
    "AAATGGAAGTACCCTA-1", "AACAACCTCCCTCGAT-1", "AACAAGAGTCAGATTC-1", 
    "AACAGGGAGGTGCATG-1", "AACCAACAGAAATGGG-1", "AACCACAAGTTACGTC-1", 
    "AACCACACAAATGCGG-1", "AACCACACACCAGTAT-1", "AACCACATCCCGTTGT-1", 
    "AACCATGCATGACAGG-1", "AACCTGAAGGTAGATT-1", "AACCTTTTCCGCAACG-1", 
    "AAGAACAGTCGTTGGC-1", "AAGCGAGGTCGCGTTG-1", "AAGCGAGTCTAAGCCA-1", 
    "AAGCGTTAGAGAGCAA-1", "AAGCGTTAGCCTGTGC-1")), x = c(1, 1, 
    1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
    2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 10, 1, 2, 1, 5, 3, 1, 5, 2, 6, 2, 1, 
    1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 20, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 
    1, 3, 1), factors = list()), data = new("dgCMatrix", i = c(3L, 
8L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 5L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 8L, 9L, 
18L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 8L, 8L, 13L, 15L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
15L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 8L, 13L, 2L, 8L, 
13L, 14L, 1L, 8L, 14L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 3L, 8L, 
13L, 14L, 3L, 8L, 1L), p = c(0L, 5L, 9L, 13L, 16L, 19L, 20L, 
23L, 30L, 30L, 33L, 39L, 41L, 45L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 55L, 59L, 61L, 
62L), Dim = c(20L, 20L), Dimnames = list(c("AL627309.5", "LINC01409", 
"FAM87B", "LINC01128", "LINC00115", "FAM41C", "AL645608.2", "SAMD11", 
"NOC2L", "KLHL17", "PLEKHN1", "PERM1", "AL645608.7", "HES4", 
"ISG15", "AGRN", "C1orf159", "TTLL10", "TNFRSF18", "TNFRSF4"), 
    c("AAACGAAAGAGAACCC-1", "AAACGCTGTACGCTAT-1", "AAAGGGCAGTAACCGG-1", 
    "AAATGGAAGTACCCTA-1", "AACAACCTCCCTCGAT-1", "AACAAGAGTCAGATTC-1", 
    "AACAGGGAGGTGCATG-1", "AACCAACAGAAATGGG-1", "AACCACAAGTTACGTC-1", 
    "AACCACACAAATGCGG-1", "AACCACACACCAGTAT-1", "AACCACATCCCGTTGT-1", 
    "AACCATGCATGACAGG-1", "AACCTGAAGGTAGATT-1", "AACCTTTTCCGCAACG-1", 
    "AAGAACAGTCGTTGGC-1", "AAGCGAGGTCGCGTTG-1", "AAGCGAGTCTAAGCCA-1", 
    "AAGCGTTAGAGAGCAA-1", "AAGCGTTAGCCTGTGC-1")), x = c(1, 1, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 10, 1, 2, 1, 5, 3, 1, 5, 2, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 20, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1), factors = list()), 
    scale.data = structure(numeric(0), .Dim = c(0L, 0L)), key = "rna_", 
    assay.orig = NULL, var.features = character(0), meta.features = structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = c("AL627309.5", 
    "LINC01409", "FAM87B", "LINC01128", "LINC00115", "FAM41C", 
    "AL645608.2", "SAMD11", "NOC2L", "KLHL17", "PLEKHN1", "PERM1", 
    "AL645608.7", "HES4", "ISG15", "AGRN", "C1orf159", "TTLL10", 
    "TNFRSF18", "TNFRSF4"), class = "data.frame"), misc = list())), 
    meta.data = structure(list(orig.ident = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Brain_Tumor_3p_raw_feature_bc_matrix", class = "factor"), 
        nCount_RNA = c(8, 7, 9, 4, 4, 2, 5, 17, 0, 8, 19, 2, 
        5, 3, 1, 1, 26, 7, 4, 1), nFeature_RNA = c(5L, 4L, 4L, 
        3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
        4L, 2L, 1L), percent.Brain_Tumor_3p_filtered_feature_bc_matrix_seurat = c(5.73453284414736, 
        6.01779506968141, 3.55912743972445, 4.50131444820001, 
        1.02573056022348, 4.88421052631579, 3.52807510614124, 
        1.07083296761169, 9.39285409738211, 6.73866576667792, 
        4.57610789980732, 0.617430539064355, 6.66001496632577, 
        2.96102465225176, 4.46445802508845, 4.89557004123986, 
        7.83134851813312, 2.82530215036886, 5.54443053817272, 
        2.95155221072437)), row.names = c("AAACGAAAGAGAACCC-1", 
    "AAACGCTGTACGCTAT-1", "AAAGGGCAGTAACCGG-1", "AAATGGAAGTACCCTA-1", 
    "AACAACCTCCCTCGAT-1", "AACAAGAGTCAGATTC-1", "AACAGGGAGGTGCATG-1", 
    "AACCAACAGAAATGGG-1", "AACCACAAGTTACGTC-1", "AACCACACAAATGCGG-1", 
    "AACCACACACCAGTAT-1", "AACCACATCCCGTTGT-1", "AACCATGCATGACAGG-1", 
    "AACCTGAAGGTAGATT-1", "AACCTTTTCCGCAACG-1", "AAGAACAGTCGTTGGC-1", 
    "AAGCGAGGTCGCGTTG-1", "AAGCGAGTCTAAGCCA-1", "AAGCGTTAGAGAGCAA-1", 
    "AAGCGTTAGCCTGTGC-1"), class = "data.frame"), active.assay = "RNA", 
    active.ident = structure(c(`AAACGAAAGAGAACCC-1` = 1L, `AAACGCTGTACGCTAT-1` = 1L, 
    `AAAGGGCAGTAACCGG-1` = 1L, `AAATGGAAGTACCCTA-1` = 1L, `AACAACCTCCCTCGAT-1` = 1L, 
    `AACAAGAGTCAGATTC-1` = 1L, `AACAGGGAGGTGCATG-1` = 1L, `AACCAACAGAAATGGG-1` = 1L, 
    `AACCACAAGTTACGTC-1` = 1L, `AACCACACAAATGCGG-1` = 1L, `AACCACACACCAGTAT-1` = 1L, 
    `AACCACATCCCGTTGT-1` = 1L, `AACCATGCATGACAGG-1` = 1L, `AACCTGAAGGTAGATT-1` = 1L, 
    `AACCTTTTCCGCAACG-1` = 1L, `AAGAACAGTCGTTGGC-1` = 1L, `AAGCGAGGTCGCGTTG-1` = 1L, 
    `AAGCGAGTCTAAGCCA-1` = 1L, `AAGCGTTAGAGAGCAA-1` = 1L, `AAGCGTTAGCCTGTGC-1` = 1L
    ), .Label = "Brain_Tumor_3p_raw_feature_bc_matrix", class = "factor"), 
    graphs = list(), neighbors = list(), reductions = list(), 
    images = list(), project.name = "Brain_Tumor_3p_raw_feature_bc_matrix", 
    misc = list(), version = structure(list(c(4L, 1L, 0L)), class = c("package_version", 
    "numeric_version")), commands = list(), tools = list())
```

perform TPM normalization on matrix:

```r
mat <- GetAssayData(object = Brain_Tumor_3p_filtered_feature_bc_matrix_seurat[['RNA']], slot = 'data')

# generate tpm matrix
tpms <- NormalizeTPM(mat, tr_length = NULL, log = FALSE,scale = 1, pseudo.count = log(0))
#> Converting input to matrix.
```

pad matrix:

```r
Y <- mat
Y[] <- NaN
Y[rownames(tpms), colnames(tpms)] <- tpms
Brain_Tumor_3p_filtered_feature_bc_matrix_seurat[["TPMcounts"]] <- CreateAssayObject(data = Y)
```

check:

```r
GetAssayData(object =  Brain_Tumor_3p_filtered_feature_bc_matrix_seurat[['TPMcounts']], slot = 'data')
#> 20 x 20 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>    [[ suppressing 20 column names 'AAACGAAAGAGAACCC-1', 'AAACGCTGTACGCTAT-1', 'AAAGGGCAGTAACCGG-1' ... ]]
#>                                                                          
#> AL627309.5       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
#> LINC01409        NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
#> FAM87B          .         .         .        .        .   .           .  
#> LINC01128  187341.27      .    146401.8      .   596565.6 .           .  
#> LINC00115       .         .         .        .        .   .           .  
#> FAM41C          .    210047.97      .        .        .   .           .  
#> AL645608.2       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
#> SAMD11          .         .         .        .        .   .           .  
#> NOC2L       92127.65  85065.63  71995.1 407352.4 146684.7  1e+06 141034.5
#> KLHL17          .         .         .   271386.5      .   .           .  
#> PLEKHN1         .         .         .        .        .   .           .  
#> PERM1            NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
#> AL645608.7       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
#> HES4       236763.77 109307.36 277536.1      .        .   .      362452.2
#> ISG15      483767.32 595579.05 504067.0      .   256749.7 .           .  
#> AGRN            .         .         .        .        .   .      496513.3
#> C1orf159        .         .         .        .        .   .           .  
#> TTLL10          .         .         .        .        .   .           .  
#> TNFRSF18        .         .         .   321261.1      .   .           .  
#> TNFRSF4         .         .         .        .        .   .           .  
#>                                                                              
#> AL627309.5       NaN NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN
#> LINC01409        NaN NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN
#> FAM87B          .    NaN      .        .         .   112796.1      .   .     
#> LINC01128       .    NaN      .    86070.04      .        .        .   .     
#> LINC00115   54197.99 NaN      .        .         .        .        .   .     
#> FAM41C          .    NaN      .        .         .        .        .   .     
#> AL645608.2       NaN NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN
#> SAMD11          .    NaN      .        .         .        .        .   .     
#> NOC2L      113883.29 NaN 166158.0 211630.63 437641.2 352391.7 363589.9  1e+06
#> KLHL17          .    NaN      .        .         .        .        .   .     
#> PLEKHN1         .    NaN      .        .         .        .        .   .     
#> PERM1            NaN NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN
#> AL645608.7       NaN NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN    NaN
#> HES4       731686.92 NaN 106754.6 108776.18 562358.8 226407.5      .   .     
#> ISG15           .    NaN 727087.4 444513.63      .   308404.7 636410.1 .     
#> AGRN       100231.79 NaN      .   149009.52      .        .        .   .     
#> C1orf159        .    NaN      .        .         .        .        .   .     
#> TTLL10          .    NaN      .        .         .        .        .   .     
#> TNFRSF18        .    NaN      .        .         .        .        .   .     
#> TNFRSF4         .    NaN      .        .         .        .        .   .     
#>                                                  
#> AL627309.5    NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
#> LINC01409     NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
#> FAM87B     .           .         .        .   NaN
#> LINC01128  .       61187.73 217397.9 403992.9 NaN
#> LINC00115  .           .         .        .   NaN
#> FAM41C     .           .         .        .   NaN
#> AL645608.2    NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
#> SAMD11     .           .         .        .   NaN
#> NOC2L       1e+06  60179.81 320725.2 596007.1 NaN
#> KLHL17     .           .         .        .   NaN
#> PLEKHN1    .           .         .        .   NaN
#> PERM1         NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
#> AL645608.7    NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN NaN
#> HES4       .      773296.62 274749.6      .   NaN
#> ISG15      .      105335.83 187127.3      .   NaN
#> AGRN       .           .         .        .   NaN
#> C1orf159   .           .         .        .   NaN
#> TTLL10     .           .         .        .   NaN
#> TNFRSF18   .           .         .        .   NaN
#> TNFRSF4    .           .         .        .   NaN
```

Alternatively, after calculating the TPM matrix, subset to the features in `mat`; you could then successfully run the inital command:

```r
btf <- subset(Brain_Tumor_3p_filtered_feature_bc_matrix_seurat, features=rownames(tpms))
NormalizeTPM(sce=as.SingleCellExperiment(btf), tr_length = NULL, log = FALSE, scale = 1, pseudo.count = log(0))
#> Converting input to matrix.
#> class: SingleCellExperiment 
#> dim: 15 20 
#> metadata(0):
#> assays(4): counts logcounts tpm normcounts
#> rownames(15): FAM87B LINC01128 ... TNFRSF18 TNFRSF4
#> rowData names(0):
#> colnames(20): AAACGAAAGAGAACCC-1 AAACGCTGTACGCTAT-1 ...
#>   AAGCGTTAGAGAGCAA-1 AAGCGTTAGCCTGTGC-1
#> colData names(5): orig.ident nCount_RNA nFeature_RNA
#>   percent.Brain_Tumor_3p_filtered_feature_bc_matrix_seurat ident
#> reducedDimNames(0):
#> mainExpName: RNA
#> altExpNames(1): TPMcounts
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>